# Второе рождение JavaScript

Tags: javascript, работа

Правда ли то, что JavaScript сейчас переживает 2-е рождение и его изучение - перспективное занятие?

Будет ли в ближайшем будущем (3-5 лет) увеличения количества вакансий для JavaScript программистов, повысится ли на них спрос?

Comment: Безусловно. Это и AJAX-подход (асинхронное взаимодействие клиента с сервером), и HTML5 (один canvas чего стоит). Плюс многие среды рабочего стола сейчас стали поддерживать возможность создания приложений на JavaScript, например, Gnome и KDE, да и Windows тоже. То есть экосистема JavaScript существенно расширилась в последние пару лет, значит, должен расти и спрос на разработчиков.

Comment: Интересно, не получится ли как с манагерами в 90-е)) Профицит тоже штука страшная)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я тоже о таком слышал. И, на сколько я понял, ожидается грандиозный фурор в данном направлении. Сейчас ведутся активные разработки для создания оконных приложений при помощи `HTML5 CSS3 JavaScript`. И некоторые такие проекты (которые создают приложение из html, css, js), уже можно использовать. При том не только для компьютеров,- уже можно создавать кроссплатформенные приложения для мобильных смартфонов! Мало того, где-то краем глаза прочитал (не могу скинуть ссылку), что 14-й офис будет работать уже не с `VBA`, а именно с `HTML5, CSS3 и JavaScript`. Так что на сегодня, если только вы не профессиональный программист оконных приложений и к вебу вы вообще не имеете и не будете иметь никакого отношения, то знание `JS` - должно быть как должное.

Да и, если посмотреть, современные возможности `HTML5, CSS3 и JavaScript` настолько высоки, что можно создать любое красивейшее приложение! И легче, чем предоставленный инструментарий, например, `Java Swing`. Мало того, на `JavaScript` возможно писать многофункциональные и сложные приложения. Да и `JS` язык особый, который предоставляет очень много удобств. Мало того, на сколько я знаю, можно на `JS` даже строить серверные приложения!

Так что, изучив `JS`, вы в любом случае не прогадаете! Да и сейчас все сайты не обходятся без `JS`, что является еще одним плюсом в его изучении.

Answer (score 6):

С точки зрения поиска работы - за день вы его не выучите. Найти работу довольно сложно ( я имею введу на вакансию "чистого" JavaScript разработчика, хотя, **может быть** - очень скоро это измениться )

А вообще - да, перспективно, спрос повышается уже сейчас, только вот спрос этот, в основном - на JS гуру. Собственно это логично, использовать новые технологии и писать, по сути, полноценный софт, на столь специфичном языке как JS - (типа) javascript программисты, возможности которых заканчиваются на обработке события клика либо конфигурировании jquery плагина, по определению не могут.

В любом случае - JS будет править миром :D (собственно уже правит, но мы этого не замечаем). Лично мне очень интересно чем все эти движения закончатся (html5 windows api, IE support (наконецто плеать, еще немного товарисчи!1АДИН1!!), canvas (<3), workers  и много-многое другое ).

С точки зрения бизнеса язык невероятно выгоден. Заюзав некоторые готовые решения вы можете написать приложение с использованием html, css, js(сервер естественно тоже можно, но это уже по желанию) - покрыть весь рынок мобильных устройств, ну и, естественно - ваше приложение будет доступно всем из браузера. Если увидите смысл - вы можете даже собрать свое приложение в десктоп софтину. Добавить к этому простоту, мощность и удобство предлагаемых технологий, непосредственно, несомненную крутость javascript'a и картина становиться ясной до нельзя.

Но для того что-бы писать что-то большее чем `onclick` и конфига плагина jquery - нужно очень много практики и опыта, само собой, как и везде - стандартная теория программиста.
Причем практика и опыт довольно специфичны, как и сам язык собственно.

Вообщем с появлением обещанного html5 API под форточками(не соврали, сделали, но пока восьмая винда не вышла =)), с началом поддержки html5 by IE, с "устаканиванием", принятием и приведением в единому виду html5 стандарта - жизнь станет прекрасной (offtop: HTML5 will kill Flash!!!), для javascript разработчик, естественно =).

Ну и да, javascript так-же может использоваться на сервере и во многих-многих прикладных задачах. Так-же, например - mongodb shell написан на все том-же javascript'e.

Хотя перспектив огромное множество не только в javascript разработке. Языки типа java, C#, C++ (и другие) востребованы всегда (not only guru). Соответственно путь тяжелый и довольно стремный. Но это я о сознательно глубоком и серьезном изучении языка и совместимых с ним технологий и стандартов. Так что начните учить - от базывых знаний вы точно не проиграете. А там будете смотреть по себе интересно ли вам, нужно ли и т.д.
( И сразу - notify: чуда не произойдет, какие-бы технологии не появлялись хз кому много платить не будут и, соответственно, разрывать на части, естественно, тоже )

Answer (score 4):

С развитием стандарта HTML 5 небольшое увеличение спроса на рынке труда будет! JS программисты  ценились всегда, но особенно ценятся не те кто за 2 минуты установят 5-10 плагинов к jquery, а те кто понимает как работает javascript. Те кто сможет писать интерактивные приложения без использования фреймворков. С jquery мы все проффи можем быть )

Answer (score 3):

Перенос всех ключевых приложений в веб (например, платорфма Google - Chrome), делает Web-интерфейс основным средством взаимодействия человека с компьютером. Вместо Microsoft Outlook - Google Mail, вместо Microsoft Office - Google Docs, и т.п. Как следствие само написание Web-интерфейса и средства по его разработке приобретают первостепенную важность. А JavaScript с развитием HTML5 становится основным средством разработки Web-интерфейса. Поэтому можно сказать и о "втором рождении".

Answer (score 2):

При чем тут второе рождение? Вы много знаете веб-языков, позволяющих в режиме реального времени взаимодействовать с клиентом? Кроме js'а вспоминается только actionscript и java, но они требуют установки плагинов и запускаются в своем окружении. Поэтому "родной" язык один - javascript.

Comment: @ling - как я понял тут речь немного о другом. Да и, как-бы, не браузером единым JavaScript живет

Comment: @AlexWindHope, согласен. Но при разработке клиентской части сайта от js'а все равно не уйти.

Comment: @ling - не спорю =)